# st_clusterdbscan not available but postgis being installed on postgresql

Tags: postgresql, postgis, heroku-postgres, geos

I'm trying to use the st_clusterdbscan-function of postgis described [here](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-dev/ST_ClusterDBSCAN.html) on a heroku / AWS postgresql instance. In the doc it says it is available since 2.3 and requires geos. postgis is installed in v 2.4 with geos:

```
select postgis_version();
2.4 USE_GEOS=1 USE_PROJ=1 USE_STATS=1
(1 row)
```

but trying to use the function (sql was taken from the official documentation) gives me

```
SELECT ST_ClusterDBSCAN(location, eps := 50, minpoints := 2) over () AS cid                  
FROM users;
ERROR:  function st_clusterdbscan(geography, eps => integer, minpoints => integer) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT ST_ClusterDBSCAN(location, eps := 50, minpoints := 2)...
           ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You 
might need to add explicit type casts.
```

What am I doing wrong? Other postgis functions like ST_DWITHIN are available and working.

Comment: I know it isn't an answer but the function does exist on my Windows instance postgis version 2.4

Comment: what does 'select postgis_version()' give you? thanks!

Comment: eps is specified as an integer, but the function expects a float. Try `ST_ClusterDBSCAN(location, 50::float, 2)`

Comment: select proname      FROM pg_proc  where proname ilike 'st_clusterdbscan%'; -- gives "st_clusterdbscan"

select postgis_version(); -- gives

"2.4 USE_GEOS=1 USE_PROJ=1 USE_STATS=1"

Answer (score 2):

it was a type-problem actually. eps needs to be casted to float and my 'location' needed to be casted to 'geometry', then it worked. thanks all.